# What are those error means? such as: [ERROR]

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins

[What are those 'ERRORS' mean in red, I did everything and also some solution mentioned in other StackOverflow forum but still doesn't work? The path is correct but why its saying cant it locate it? I am trying to do it in Jenkins for CI. I checked the configuration in Jenkins and everything looks perfectly fine. Please help]

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/JavaLearner/.jenkins/workspace/CVSPharmacyTestJob/src/main/java/com/cvs/qa/pages/ClinicLocator.java:[9,28] package com.cvs.qa.testcases does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactArchiver$2; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.510 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-11T03:42:56-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project CvsPharmacyTest: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/JavaLearner/.jenkins/workspace/CVSPharmacyTestJob/src/main/java/com/cvs/qa/pages/ClinicLocator.java:[9,28] package com.cvs.qa.testcases does not exist
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Do not link only images better copy&paste the text into the post and format it well...

Comment: @shuwaib, could you please paste the entire log here? It will help analyse the problem.